# How to connect the following two ideas by « inversement » or « par contre », or something else?

Tags: choix-de-mot

I just wrote in an email:

> Je ne sais que trop bien ce que ça fait de taper les lettres japonaises sur un clavier français. Parce que, **inversement**, on s'arrache les cheveux pour les accents français ! Peut-être qu’il vaudrait mieux que tu poses cette question sur le SE ? Je viens d'ailleurs de tomber sur cette page :

I wonder which adverb or adverbial phrase is well suited to comparing these two sentences, as well as where to place it.

Comment: Maybe replacing "parce que" with "**mais**" would permit you to use one of these adverbs of opposition to capture the (less important) switching/swapping notion without detracting from the (more important, imo) notion of sympathy/empathy (& I'd change "ca fait" to "ca doit faire") (Je ne sais que trop bien ce que ça doit faire de taper les lettres japonaises sur un clavier français. Mais nous/ici, par contre, on s'arrache les cheveux pour les accents français!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use a word that means a strong opposition, because you want to say it's the **same thing** with French accents. I would better say:

> Parce que, **de la même manière**, on s'arrache [...]

It's more a parallel, a comparison, than an opposition.

And I couldn't explain why but the use of *"parce que"* with *"inversement"* sounds strange. This sounds better to me:

> Et, inversement, on s'arrache [...]

Still, I wouldn't say your sentence is wrong, French people could use it this way.

Comment: Hi. Jiliagre has pointed out that "inversement" is not suitable for use here. What's your take on it? :) To elaborate on the reason why I used "inversement": "**Vous avez du mal à taper les lettres japonaises sur un clavier français**" alors que  "**Nous avons du mal à taper les lettres accentuées françaises  sur un clavier japonais**". I tend to use "inversement" when the elements in the mentioned two ideas are kind of switched/swapped around, in a manner of speaking. And this sentence seems to call for its use. At the same time, though, I was ambivalent about placing it here. Merci.

Comment: @Ahalone-zee I get why you used *inversement* and it makes sens, that's why I didn't say it's wrong, but it just sound strange. As Papa Poule noted, replacing *parce que* with *mais* makes the use of *inversement* sound better.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use *inversement* because it means "on the opposite* while in fact, you describe a similar situation.

What you want to state is there is some symmetry, you might then replace *inversement* by *de notre côté aussi*:

> Parce que, **de notre côté aussi**, on s'arrache les cheveux pour les accents français !

Comment: Hi. What do you think of the following versions, with those adverbs placed at the end? "Parce qu'on s'arrache les cheveux pour les accents français, **en revanche / inversement / à l'inverse** !" Are you still against using them? Can you also take a look at the comment I've left under Simon Déchamps' answer? Merci. :)

Comment: Ok, I got the idea now but *en revanche, inversement* or *à l'inverse* are still not right semantically, even if they might be possible mathematically. That would work if you said *en revanche, nous on n'a pas de problème avec les accents français.*